# Добавить фон для счётчика уведомлений в Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

**Задача:** Нужно добавить фон для счётчика уведомлений в `Navigation Drawer`.
**Проблема:** При добавлении `background`, `height` остаётся равным элементу.
Добавлял `<shape>`, но установленая там высота не учитывается.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_notifications"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications"
    android:title="@string/notifications" />
```

---

```
notify = nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications).actionView as TextView
        notify.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
        notify.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
        notify.setTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorAccent, null))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так я реализовывал данную задачу:

```
private static void initCounterInNavView(Context context, TextView tv, RealmResults results) {
    final Resources resources = context.getResources();
    int dp = (int) resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    Log.e("Density", "" + dp);
    NavigationView.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(40 * dp, 40 * dp);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corners);
    tv.setTextSize(14);
    tv.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.nav_counter_text_view_color, context.getTheme()));
    ToolsViews.counterStyleAndUpdate(tv, results.size(), ToolsViews.TWO_SYMBOL_IN_COUNTER);
}
```

где: result - ваше значение.
Особенно обратите внимание на 5-ю строчку, именно она мне кровушки то и попила...

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!